# Try to pass ref data to prop of component before parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello I have Dots and Carousel component:

```
<Dots :carousel="$refs.carousel" />
<div>
  some data
</div>
<carousel
    ref="carousel"
    :per-page="4"
    :autoplay="true"
    :autoplay-timeout="3000"
    :mouse-drag="false"
>
  ....
</carousel>
```

When I try pass to prop on Dots component, I get undefined in prop data, why? I need Dots component to be before the Carousel component. This is important. I think, that this is reason why does not it work. If I put Dots component after carousel component, then working good.

In Dots component I have:

```
export default {
  name: 'Dots',
  props: ['carousel']
}
```

In mounted when I try call `console.log(this.carousel)`, I get undifined. But I need get a component data of Carousel. How I can do it?

Sandbox test: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-monad-5bhjz?file=/src/components/Test.vue

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to have Dot before your Carousel for aesthetic reason you can reorder your template (eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/order).

You will be able to put you Dot component after Carousel to get its ref, but it will be show before.